# How do I get the number of permutations of the elements in a list that do not have consecutive repeating characters?

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I want the number of permutations of a group of numbers that do not have consecutive repeating characters beside eachother.

If I have a function `number_of_permutations` with an input of `(['1', '2', '3'])`, I want it to return 6 since none of it's permutations have consecutively repeating characters.

123,
132,
213,
231,
312,
321

But if I have the parameter `(['1', '4', '1'])`, I want it to return 2 since only two permutations do not have consecutively repeating characters.

141,
141

How do I do this in python using recursion?

Comment: What does `141, 141` mean here? When you say "has no repeating characters", do you mean no *consecutive* repeated characters?

Comment: I don't understand what fo you mean by repeating character.

Comment: You can remove duplicates in a list of hashable values by first converting it to a `set` and them back into `list` (but order will not be preserved).

Comment: The question has been changed. By 'repeating characters', I meant 'consecutively repeating characters'

Answer (score 0):

In case we can forego `recursion` as a requirement, you can use `itertools.permutations` and a O(n) loop to solve this. Complexity stays the same as calculating all permutations and equal to the worst case scenario of an optimized algorithm.

```py
from typing import Iterator
import itertools


def number_of_permutations(possibilities: list) -> Iterator:
    for potential in itertools.permutations(possibilities):
        for i, c in enumerate(potential):
            try:
                if c == potential[i+1]:
                    break 
            except IndexError:
                yield potential
```

Comment: O(n)???? The number of permutations is exponential, not linear. *"Complexity stays the same as calculating all permutations and equal to the worst case scenario of an optimized algorithm."* Do you have any proof to support this claim? The question is only asking to calculate the number of permutations, not to generate them. Possibly there exists an algorithm to calculate that number directly without generating the permutations. Generating the permutations is **slow** because there are so many of them. How do you know that your algorithm has the same complexity as "an optimized algorithm"?